# How do I build macports 2.6.3 on Mac OS X Big Sur Beta? "Unsupported architecture" error

Tags: macports, macos-big-sur

I am getting build errors when I build MacPorts on my iMac running the latest Big Sur beta.  Yeah I know, it's beta, but I think my question is still relevant.  Please see below for the full error message (first error of many).   Thanks for any help!

```
clang -MM -MP -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/Users/rcook/current_projects/macports-base/src -I/Users/rcook/current_projects/macports-base/src -I. -I/Users/rcook/current_projects/macports-base/vendor/vendor-destroot/opt/local/libexec/macports/include -I./../compat access.c > access.d
clang -g -O2 -std=c99 -Wextra -Wall   -fPIC -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/Users/rcook/current_projects/macports-base/src -I/Users/rcook/current_projects/macports-base/src -I. -I/Users/rcook/current_projects/macports-base/vendor/vendor-destroot/opt/local/libexec/macports/include -I./../compat  -c -o access.o access.c
In file included from access.c:36:
In file included from ./darwintrace.h:40:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:55:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:32:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
```

Comment: Have you created a ticket for this over at MacPorts support?

https://trac.macports.org

Comment: Yes, I just did, thanks.  I felt I had to wait for the beta period to be over.  Now I'm using a supported version and I can go to their bug reporting page.  Before, there did not seem to be a way to discuss Big Sur issues with macPorts.

Comment: Discussing problems with MacPorts on beta versions of MacOS is 100% okay. You'll find plenty of threads like that.

Comment: Well here is how it all turned out for me if you are curious:  https://trac.macports.org/ticket/61495  cheers

Comment: Discussing beta versions of macOS or Xcode with MacPorts publicly is not ok; please see https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#prerelease